# Consider piles of red, blue, and green balls where each pile contains at least 10 balls...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> Consider piles of red, blue, and green balls where each pile contains at least 10 balls. In how many ways can $10$ balls be selected if at most $1$ red ball is selected?

I've seen answers to similar problems but I'm not sure how to arrive at the conclusion myself. I was given $^{10 + 2-1}C_{10} + {}^{9+2-1}C_9$ but I'm not quite sure where the "$2-1$" comes from and what not.

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$\left(\!\binom nk\!\right)$ denotes the number of choosing $k$ out of $n$ things with repetition allowed, and order not important; it is given by $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. This is called [*multichoose*](http://multichoose.net/), and it's where the "$2-1$" comes from.

The Wikipedia article on [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is also helpful to understand this concept, there is a [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA) on YouTube too.

---

**Solution**: There are red, blue and green balls. You can choose at most one red ball. Thus if you choose the red ball, then you have $9$ balls left to choose, basically which of them are blue, and which are green. This can be done in $\left(\!\binom29\!\right) = \binom{2+9-1}{9}=10$ ways.

On the other hand, if you do *not* choose the red ball, then you choose 10 balls, either blue or green. This can be done in $\left(\!\binom2{10}\!\right) = \binom{2+10-1}{10}=11$ ways.

Thus the answer is $10+11=21$ ways.

Comment: Your use of the notation $\left( \binom{n}{k} \right)$ is inconsistent.  In your solution, you inverted the numbers $n$ and $k$.

Comment: In each case, we are choosing $k$ out of $2$ colours (repetition allowed). How did I invert them?

Comment: I see.  So what you meant was $\left(\binom{n}{k}\right)$ is the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from $n$ types of objects.  That clarifies things.

Comment: From $n$ with repetition allowed, yes. I too found it strange at first having the small number at the top!